# Auto Refresh in Smart View using a Macro

Tags: macros, refresh

I am trying to create a macro that will automatically refresh my data in Smart View.  I need to be able to have it run automatically without opening the file.  I am new to macros and I am not an expert so if someone can help me it would be very much appreciated.  It needs to refresh daily by itself.

This is the code I have

```
    Sub RefreshWB()

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    If Sheets(i).Visible Then
        Sheets(i).Select
        Call HypMenuVRefresh
        i = i + 1
        Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
Sub RefreshWS()
  x = HypMenuVRefresh()
End Sub
```

For some reason the loop to refresh all pages errors out.  I think it has to do with Sheets(i).Select line.  But I need to automate this macros without having to go into the file to run the macros.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the code you have written so far to your question to help us understand your question better.

Comment: I haven't written any code.  I am using Smart View (oracle) and I am trying to create a code that will auto refresh my file without me having to be in it

Comment: Sub refreshing()
'
' refreshing Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Retrieve").Names.Add Name:= _
        "'Retrieve'!EssbasePRD1_CableGL_Main_1", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=Retrieve!R5C2:R696C54"
End Sub

Comment: You need to add what you have tried so far to your question. Please go over [how to write a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question and get answers faster.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code to the question.

Comment: The post has been edited